# Generate Multiple files based on Bookkeeping File

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have two files

- File1:  Size 100 bytes that contain actual data
- File2: Contains an array of numbers in the below format

  ```
  10
  10
  80
  ```

So, I need to generate 3 different files

- File a of size 10 bytes which contains first 10 bytes of data from File 1
- File b of size 10 bytes which contains second 10  bytes of data from File 1
- File C of size 80 bytes which contains remaining 80 bytes of data from File 1.

I am stuck on how to intergrate this in shell script. Can someone please help ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. First, why does file `C` have a size of 80 bytes, but only contains 10 bytes? Second, you don't include `file2` in the question. You probably mean that the parameters 10, 10 and 80 come from `file2`. Change your question to make that explicit. Also include what you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: If I understand you right, you read the three lines from `file2`. As you read each line, you use it as a parameter to the `head` command (EDIT: Not sure about `head`). The output of that goes to files `A`, `B` and `C`.

Comment: `tail` could also be used to copy portions of a file, or `dd`.

Comment: Sorry, typo file3 should contain remaining 80 bytes